# Hash display jquery in rails view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a hash in an rails project and what to display that in a erb file in a specific sequence and order. Each key has an array as the value
i want to display a view page with all the keys listed in a fieldset(left side) and the values are displayed in another fieldset (right side). Each of this entry in the fieldset has a radio button. By default the first entry in the right side field set is selected and ONLY the values of that key should be shown on the right hand side. 
 if the selection of the key changes on the left side, the right side should show ONLY the values corresponding to the key selected. I want to do this is in jquery. Any suggestions? Thank you. 
a = { 1 => [me], 2 => [me,you], 3 => [what,is,this] } 

default view (* is selected, - not selected)
 * 1      * me 
 - 2
 - 3
On change
 - 1      * me 
 * 2      - you
 - 3
On change
 - 1      * what
 - 2      - is
 * 3      - this
On change
 * 1      * me 
 - 2
 - 3

Comment: I would like to have some tips on how to best order the div/li and reference them. Click events and basic jquery stuff is handled. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are, by definition, un-ordered. Rails will maintain their order for you, but you should get in the habit of using arrays if you want to guarantee a certain order.

User jQuery click events are probably what you're looking for:

```
$(document).on('click', '#someRadioButton', function(e) {
  $('.relevantValues').show();
  $('.irrelevantValues').hide();
});
```

Comment: Code does the ordering and the hash is ordered to the needs and rightly associated. The solution that you suggested is generic and the complexity is in tagging and finding relevant and irrelevantValues.

Comment: That's the purpose of stack overflow. I give you a generic nudge, and you have something to go off of to start learning. relevent and irrelevantValues are classes you add to the html for you to differentiate between what you want to show and what you want to hide.